# UTF-8 encoding, the right way

Tags: javascript, css, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm curious, as to what is the right way to have UTF-8 encoding on all web files

**All my files (incl. CSS and JS) are made and saved in UTF-8 encoding**

In PHP, I set the char-set on top of the main page (this page includes all others) with:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

At the same page I have this html meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then I stubled upon an external css file that has this on first line:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

And now I wonder, should I set the charset INSIDE all my CSS/JS files too, like that?

And/or should I serve each file with *charset=utf-8* in the meta tag?
EDIT: this is obsolete for HTML5

Comment: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode might get you started.

Comment: If the HTML is specified as UTF-8, browsers usually assume that all linked resources (unless specified otherwise) have the same encoding. In other words, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do it if you have non-ascii characters.  Also, watch out for the note below... the file has to be saved as UTF8 as well.

From: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php

> If you have any non-ASCII text in your CSS file, for example non-ASCII
>   characters in font names, in values of the content property, in
>   selectors, etc., you need to be sure that the CSS parser knows how to
>   transform the bytes into characters correctly, so that it understands
>   your CSS code. This article describes how to do this.
>
> Note! It is not enough to simply put @charset "utf-8"; at the top of
>   the style sheet – you need to also save your style sheet in the UTF-8
>   character encoding

Comment: The OP does mention saving everything as UTF-8.

Comment: Just saw that... still, it doesn't hurt to mention it, since it seems to be a common problem from unicode-related posts.

Comment: Sometimes text in BOLD has the opposite effect :D